# How do I reconfigure and build a Xcode Project that doesn't have Prefix.pch

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode Project. For some reason there is no precompiled header(No ProjectNamePrefix.pch files provided in the project) Someone must turned it off when they created this project.

Now when I try to build the project there is always an error saying Clang can't find the ProjectNamePrefix.pch file inside the project directory.

I have already turned off Precompiled Header in Building settings and deleted Derived Data folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to your target, then to build settings and find prefix header. Then remove it (or add file with such path, if you need it) [image: Prefix header path]

Answer (score 0):

- Create your `.pch` file
- Under `Build Settings` for the relevant target search for 'prefix' and under `Prefix Header` add the path to your `.pch` file, in the same section and also be sure to set `Precompile Prefix Header` to `Yes`.

[image]